# cxfreeze aiohttp cannot import compat

Tags: python, python-3.5, cx-freeze

I'm trying to use `cx_freeze` to build a binary dist for an web application written in Python 3 using the `aiohttp` package.

Basically I did:

```
cxfreeze server.py
```

and got a `dist` output

But when running the `./server` binary, I got the following message:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 12, in <module>
    __import__(name + "__init__")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 24, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "server.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .protocol import *  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/protocol.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import errors, hdrs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/errors.py", line 3, in <module>
    from asyncio import TimeoutError
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . import compat

ImportError: cannot import name 'compat'
```

Answer (score 16):

Hopefully you've been able to fix this already, but for people searching this question like I was, I'll answer:

This `compat` module is part of `asyncio`, and not getting discovered by cx_Freeze. I had to add `asyncio` to the `packages` list in the `build_exe` options in `setup.py` to get it to be included:

```
setup(
    ...
    options = {
        'build_exe': {
            'packages': ['encodings', 'asyncio']
        },
    }
)
```

Comment: The following fixed it for me in `setup.py`:
`buildOptions = dict(packages = ['asyncio'], excludes = [])`

Comment: setup.py of what ? of the pplication using it ?

Comment: does cxfreeze somehow detect a setup.py in the directory?