# Python 3.x + PyQt5 + py2exe/pyinstaller/cx-Freeze

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze

I have been exploring the options for how to freeze my package that uses [flask-desktop](https://github.com/Widdershin/flask-desktop/). Qt does a lot of the heavy-lifting, and as such it is a pretty big library.

I experimented with several options to see what I could do. Python versions here indicate explicit support for each package.

```
|                 |Python 3.4|Python 3.5|Python 3.6|Runs*  |Works**|
|-----------------|----------|----------|----------|-------|-------|
|PyQt4            |Yes       |Yes       |Yes       |?      |?      |
|PyQt5 (5.8.2)    |No        |Yes       |Yes       |Yes    |Yes    |
|cx-Freeze (5.0.1)|Yes       |Yes       |Yes       |Yes    |Yes    |
|py2exe (0.9.2.2) |Yes       |No        |No        |Yes    |No     |
|pyinstaller***   |Yes       |Yes***    |No        |Yes    |No     |
```

<sub>*Command executes or package imports without errors</sub>

<sub>**Result of command is valid (i.e. produces working freeze)</sub>

<sub>***Supported in dev branch</sub>

I have tried using the latest versions of py2exe and pyinstaller with Python 3.4/3.5/3.6 separately with no success. The errors I receive are different and complicated each time, and my debugging and research into it was unsuccessful for each pairing of Python version and either freezer package. I won't have enough time to delve into that anytime soon.

PyQt4 is not a practical option because it lacks some very important features like HiDPI support and it uses deprecated QtWebKit.

PyQt5 is only compatible with Python 3.5 and up because its `sip` package requires it.

py2exe supports UPX and single file (.exe) output but doesn't go past Python 3.4.

pyinstaller dev branch runs in 3.5, but I could not get it to copy binaries to the output directory properly. Every time I run it I get a error messages about not being able to find Qt5 libs. It's different ones each time I run it.

cx-Freeze, on the other hand, is working with some [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669260/) in `setup.py`:

```
build_options = dict(
    packages = ['encodings', 'asyncio', 'jinja2'],
    ...
)
```

Now this is great. It produces a working freeze but my only remaining concern is how should I turn this 300MB folder of frozen *stuff* (70 files/folders!) into something a little more manageable (ideally under 30MB)? For example, all of the (pre-compiled) Qt5 libraries are copied into the destination twice, in two different paths: `build\exe.win-amd64-3.6` and `build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\PyQt5\Qt\bin`. I can delete the DLLs in `build\exe.win-amd64-3.6` and the program still runs fine. And the dependency `QtWebEngineCore.dll` weighs in at 65MB (uncompressed) and about 26MB after running it through UPX on `-9` maximum compression (that's a good start).

My goal is to minimize the footprint of my application, and currently, my flask-python program is a memory hog:

My flask-desktop program hogging a lotta memory

[image]

What suggestions do you have for having (Py)Qt5-based application using QtWebEngine use less memory? Also, I'm not familiar with cx-Freeze, so I would love to know if anyone could suggest how I can reduce the build output size with it or how I might get another package freezer to work with Python 3.5/3.6 and PyQt5.

I feel like I have explored a lot of options here but I am still running into difficult limitations because of Python/package version incompatibilities. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's May 2018, can confirm pyinstaller python 3.6 pyqt5 still doesn't work. Reading this is reaffirming.